# Slowness in a simple animation using the Timer class

Tags: java, animation

A small app containing a `BufferedImage` uses the Timer class for animation. Everything works, but not as expected.

Sometimes the system struggles to draw the animation, as though it is draining system resources (especially after installing the JRE), which makes the animation redraw at abnormally low speeds. Other times it works as expected.

What could cause this?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please post some of the code.

Comment: `java.util.Timer` or `javax.swing.Timer`?

Comment: "What could cause this?"  -- a problem with your code.  If you want more details, you're going to have to provide a lot more detail yourself.

Comment: Some code is now provided below..!Could you specify what parts of the code are the most likely ones to have the problem?

Comment: Just realised that I can replicate the problem if I clear out the java cache from the control panel..! Then after 10-20 runs, it gets back to full speed again..!

Answer (score 1):

Switch to java.util.Timer, javax.swing.Timer seems to be better suited to actions that are called every minute or second as opposed to java.util.Timer which is far better adapted to tens of calls per second.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone..my bad!

The class I am using is javax.swing.Timer!

Here is part of the code (timer implementation -- not the method timer calls):

```
Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(10, new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){

        //This little if/step statement actually decides if 
        //the ellipses I have on screen will be colored all together 
        //or step by step

        if(app.flagStep == false){
            for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
                drawBuffer(i);
            }
        }
        else{
            if(app.stepBut.isEnabled()){
                app.stepBut.setEnabled(false);
            }
            drawBuffer(app.myStep);
        }


    }
});
```